# How to add my photo to SU account?

Tags: support, gravatar

I tired to add my photo to my profile, it redireted me to Gravatar i added my photo there, then what, i don't understand the next step.. Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like your photo worked fine. It can take a few minutes for the change to propagate. For future reference, see "[How do I change my picture or avatar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar)" on Meta.Stackoverflow.

Comment: the original poster of this question was http://meta.superuser.com/users/74915/albouazizi.

Comment: @Mat, this has been [reported as a bug](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2394/migrated-question-showing-wrong-account-as-asker). Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing, your photo is coming up just fine here.