# Migrated question showing wrong account as asker

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

[This question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2392/how-to-add-my-photo-to-su-account#question) was asked on SU, then migrated to MSU. The question says that the asker is the user who actually answered the question before it was migrated. The actual asker is no longer shown, and the answer is shown as not being associated with an account. The [post history](https://meta.superuser.com/posts/2392/revisions) shows the correct asker. What went wrong in the migration process?

Comment: funny thing: the right user is visible on the meta.superuser.com "homepage" right now (active view), but the wrong one on the "questions" (newest) view.

Comment: lol: I could actually accept my (very poor) answer to the question I didn't post :-)

Comment: Also, [the timeline](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/2392/timeline) has it wrong. (I cannot see [its original timeline](http://superuser.com/posts/270673/timeline) — that's an [open feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users). Maybe a moderator can see it, @Sathya and nhinkle?)

Comment: Suffice it to say, this is a very broken question.

Comment: @Arjan - I had to undelete the question to view the timeline - and here you go http://i.imgur.com/O6mRp.png

Comment: something changed today - my answer to that post is now showing correctly (linked to this account) rather than a "phantom" user, and I got the "Quorum" badge on SU proper. But now I also have badges on MSU for the question...

Comment: the issue appears to be fixed. should I open a new bug for the badges I incorrectly received for it?

Comment: @Mat I wouldn't worry about it. Who knows what caused it and how it got fixed... I guess you just got a few extra badges!

Comment: Maybe Who Knows What will also take them away at some point. I'll take good care of them in the mean time :-) thanks for looking into this anyway.

Comment: @Mat the problem is now fixed; see Jarrod's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug in our migration code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation/88066#88066); it has been fixed and the post ownership properly assigned.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod. Glad the problem's been cleared up. Do you know if the recalc on affected users will also fix erroneous badges like @Mat's?

Comment: Thanks! It didn't fix the badges though, I don't deserve [self-learner] or [student].